# how to add Arabic letters to url regex

Tags: php, regex, url, arabic

how to add Arabic letters to url in regex

```
if (!preg_match("^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$^",$_POST['url'])) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use an [Unicode chracter class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for that. It would be `\p{Arabic}` for your case. But don't forget that you should also add the Unicode PCRE modifier `/u` at the end.

Comment: Mario is right , but if you need to use full range for arabic letters 
like `[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]` and don't forget to convert the php internal encoding to Unicode

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[\pL0-9]` and don't forget the the Unicode PCRE modifier `/u` at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using its UTF-8 code: `\x123` should help.

**UPD:** the full regexp seems to be like this (for the rule `any URL part could contain arabic chars`):

`^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\x0600-\x06FF\x0750-\x077F\xFB50-\xFDFF\xFE70-\xFEFF]+\.[a-zA-Z\x0600-\x06FF\x0750-\x077F\xFB50-\xFDFF\xFE70-\xFEFF]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9\x0600-\x06FF\x0750-\x077F\xFB50-\xFDFF\xFE70-\xFEFF]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~\x0600-\x06FF\x0750-\x077F\xFB50-\xFDFF\xFE70-\xFEFF])*$`