# preg_replace and preg_match arabic characters

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, preg-match, arabic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add Arabic letters to url regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842378/how-to-add-arabic-letters-to-url-regex)

I have been searching a couple of hours without an answer.

How do you use preg_replace on arabic characters as well as english?

this is my code is english

```
$string = preg_replace ( "/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring),/", "", $string );
$string = preg_replace ( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]/", "", $string );
```

some of the answers suggested i use this code:

```
$string = preg_replace ( "/&([أ-يa-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring),/u", "", $string );
$string = preg_replace ( "/[^أ-يa-zA-Z0-9_.-]/u", "", $string );
```

I have tested it and it works. but is this actually functional for php? does it include all arabic characters? is there a better way to include all arabic characters?

What i am going to do with the code is:

Replace all characters in the string to valid SEO friendly characters.

I solved the problem using this code based on http://www.unicodemap.org. Thank you Bryan.

```
$string = preg_replace ( "/&([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring),/u", "", $string );
    $string = preg_replace ( "/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}a-zA-Z0-9_.-]/u", "", $string );
```

Comment: what are SEO friendly charactars?

Comment: Arabic has characters such as "أ إ آ ا" but the url should only include the character "ا" which is the same but without the signs.

Comment: I have already read the question you linked above, it does not help me at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [unicode character map](http://www.unicodemap.org/) is a great place to visualize the groups of characters including Arabic that the first part of the string is grouping for you with `[أ-يa-zA-Z]`

If you are still unsure, read up a little more on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: My experience in php is still in beta stages.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're making a joke or not. PHP was released nearly 20 years ago.

Comment: No no, i am saying: My experience <= means, i am still a novice, i am having a hard time understanding the links you gave me. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah okay, well don't worry about PHP, it can handle unicode just fine. Just read in my link on regular expressions the part on "meta characters". It will explain how the bracketed lists work to replace  select accented characters, then filter out an left-overs one by one.

Comment: Your post solved the problem along with inhan. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Something I see in your ranges is, you have `[أ-ي]` and I know the one on the right is the Arabic A, the first letter. I'm not familiar with the first one, but I suppose it's something like the last character. If that is the case, because PHP language is English, you might want to change the direction of your range into `[ي-أ]` instead.

Also, for normalization, I would use Unicode character ranges instead, like Bryan suggested.

Comment: أ is the first possible in the arabic language, ي is the last possible letter. due to the left to right nature of the editor, the direction of [أ-ي] is actually [a-z].

Comment: Ranges are declared in regex like **[firstChar-lastChar]**, that's why I suggested that solution.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace ( "/&([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring),/u", "", $string );`  is this an accurate assumption?

Comment: thank you, the problem is solved.

Comment: Regardless, you can use the **i** flag along with the **u** flag at the end and use only lower Basic Latin characters: `'/[a-z]/ui'`