# HTML pattern Arabic letters

Tags: html, design-patterns, arabic, letters

I want to insert the Arabic letters in the pattern just like the English letters

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]{1,30}"
```

I have no idea how to accomplish the action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range for Arabic and Persian are shared so this code could be used for Arabic too.

```
[أ-يa-zA-Z]
```

This is the reference for finding the character range of Unicode languages:

[preg_replace and preg_match arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046526/preg-replace-and-preg-match-arabic-characters)

http://unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 `pattern` attribute follows JavaScript regular expression syntax, which makes things rather awkward. You cannot test character properties, for example. Instead, you need to list down the allowed characters or ranges of characters.

Using the normative [Scripts.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt) file (by the Unicode Consortium), which defines the script (writing system) of all characters, I constructed the following:

```
pattern=
"[a-zA-Z0-9-_. \
\u0620-\u063F\u0641-\u064A\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\
\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\
\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\uFB50-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\
\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC]{1,30}"
```

Starting from the set of all characters with script defined to be Arabic, I picked up those that are declared as letters (General Category `Lo` or `Lm`), and then omitted those beyond BMP, the Basic Multilingual Plane.

Characters outside BMP are used very rarely, and to represent them in JavaScript syntax, you would need to either include the characters themselves or use two `\u` notations per character (one for each component of a surrogate pair). This does not sound realistic.

This is of course a “hardwired” solution: it may need updates if new Arabic letters are added to Unicode or the script of a character is changed from or to Arabic (which is highly unlikely). But I don’t expect to see new Arabic letters added to BMP during my lifetime.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/sanstitreyhf.png/

This is what I Got after adding the Pattern which you gave me, On the browser the name is showed well in Arabic but it maybe a problem from the server or the local-host because it's showed as non defined characters 
<pre>
PrivateImg-0489351267_Ø£Ù„ÙŠØ³Ø¨ÙŠØ¨
</pre>

Comment: What is the image supposed to show? The question was about input checking. What happens after that is a completely different issue. Please check whether the attribute does what was requested, and if there are problems with *server-side handling* of the data, please post them as separate question(s). (It sounds like it’s a matter of server-side form handler not prepared to handle data in the encoding used, but no real data was given about this, and it *is* a different question.)