# Preg matching Arabic?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, arabic

I'm attempting to preg match a link of which is half in English, half in Arabic.

The link as an example looks like:

```
"/<arabic>/123/<arabic>-<english>.html"
```

The basic `preg_match('@<a href="/(.*?).html" >);` returns everything back however the Arabic within the URL means that it is no longer identifiable to a page, returning `"Ø¯Ø§Ù†Ù„ÙˆØ¯-Ø±Ø§ÛŒÚ"` for example.

I've attempted some things I've seen such as `\p{Arabic}` however this returns nothing. Is there a way to be able to capture these links?

It's something I'm pretty stumped with and can't figure out a way around this issue.

Edit to add preg match & what I'm attempting to match.

```
preg_match_all('@<a href="/\p{Arabic}/(.*?)/\p{Arabic}-(.*?)" >@iu',$page,$link);
```

example text -

```
"a href="/دانلود-رایگان-کتاب/کتاب-های-خارجی/مطلب/2120-the-essential-financial.html"
```

Comment: could you include a code snippet including the regular expression and sample text you're trying to match against?

Comment: this post may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046526/preg-replace-and-preg-match-arabic-characters

Comment: I have just edited in the code & example text. Thanks for the link teeyo I did see that but wasn't sure if you had to know what characters were required etc. I will look into that now

Answer (score 0):

Think twice before using [regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($links as $link){
  echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```