# I want to add Arabic characters using preg_match() function

Tags: preg-match

```
function validate_name($name, $name_limit, $name_system){
    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[_-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[_-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/", $name) && strlen($name) <= $name_limit && !ctype_digit($name) && $name !== $name_system && strlen($name) >= 4){
        $valid_name = 1;
    }
    else {
        $valid_name = 0;
    }
    return $valid_name;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12046526/5517435

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_replace and preg\_match arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046526/preg-replace-and-preg-match-arabic-characters)