# Replace All Special Characters Expect Language Specific

Tags: php

Remove everything from the string expect the language-specific special signs and characters etc.
I've been using this method:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string);
```

Now it's obvious that it's not working with the following languages:
1. Arabic
2. Hindi
3. With Spanish characters.
And all the languages outside English.
Now my question is simple, what will be the best way to remove all the special characters from the string.

Comment: The [unicode character map](https://unicodemap.org/) is a great place to visualize the groups of characters including Arabic that the first part of the string is grouping for you with [أ-يa-zA-Z], then use preg_replace with an if base to lang session

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preg\_replace and preg\_match arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046526/preg-replace-and-preg-match-arabic-characters)

Comment: *"what will be the best way to remove all the special characters*" ... define "special characters". Does **ß** count as a special character? Would you want to replace it with **ss** or just drop it and leave something nonsensical? To give any kind of *reasonable* answer to this question, we could use some context - what are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: ~!@#$%^&*()_+}{:"?>< and all the characters outside any communication language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = "abcßöäü #.,}* हिंदी عربى";
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w0-9 \-]/u', '', $string);

var_dump($string);
//string(28) "abcßöäü हद عربى"
```

Whether \w works depends on the system configuration.